# How to setup mx record on registrar?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I am using namesilo.com domain registration and am trying to setup an MX record to point back to my linux server so I can install postfix. But these settings do not work:

[image: DNS Settings Screenshot]

Is there anything else I need to do? If I ping mx.wishd.me I get nothing.

```
$ ping mx.wishd.me
ping: unknown host mx.wishd.me
```

Answer (score 5):

You've mixed up the "name" and the "address value".
Also you've failed to define the `A record` for your mailsystem.

You'll need these 2 records.

```
A    mx.wishd.me ip.ad.dr.es NA 3600 
MX   wishd.me    mx.wishd.me 10 3600
```

Comment: are you sure i mixed up the name/address? Because the form only lets me enter a sub-domain in the first field.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "NAME" of your MX record to be wishd.me

To explain it a bit further:

The MX record consists of:

```
NAME, CONTENT, PRIORITY, TYPE and TTL
```

You want `NAME` to reflect the bit after the @.  E.g. myname@`example.com`

The `CONTENT` must be the hostname of the mailserver, which is supposed to handle the e-mail, for the `NAME` - in your case, wishde.me.

The `PRIORITY` must be a prioritized list of mailservers. If you have a backup mailserver, you would typically create that with `PRIORITY 20`. That would cause mailserver around the world to say "Well if the one with the lowest priority does not work - let's try the next one"

`TTL` is the Time To Live like any other record.